# Browser Cache Storage issue

Tags: reactjs, caching, browser-cache, cacheapi

I am storing 40,000 plus images in cache storage using cache.put(). I can see all the images in cache storage successfully stored. But when I am using my react js website offline, some images are displaying and some are not displaying. The browser decides itself to show an image or not. I am unable to find the reason. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution. Just we need an event listener in the Service worker. If there is GET request, it will first check-in the cache first and return from there

```
  self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  // Let the browser do its default thing
  // for non-GET requests.
  if (event.request.method !== 'GET') return;
  // Prevent the default, and handle the request ourselves.
  event.respondWith(async function() {
    // Try to get the response from a cache.
    const cache = await caches.open('images');
    const cachedResponse = await cache.match(event.request);
    if (cachedResponse) {
      // If we found a match in the cache, return it, but also
      // update the entry in the cache in the background.
      event.waitUntil(cache.add(event.request));
      return cachedResponse;
    }
    // If we didn't find a match in the cache, use the network.
    return fetch(event.request);
  }());
});
```